# Is there a way to retrieve and save server response on client (using Node.js and React Native)

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, mongoose, axios

I have a post request:

```
router.post("/projects", async (req, res) => {
  const {
    projectName,
    projectDescription,
    projectBudget,
    projectDuration,
    industry,
    companyName,
    numberOfEmployees,
    diamond,
  } = req.body;
  console.log(diamond);

//diamond is an array having structure like this: diamond[ { criteria: {...} } ]

  const [projectDiamond] = diamond;

  const { criteria } = projectDiamond;

  if (
    !projectName ||
    !projectDescription ||
    !projectBudget ||
    !projectDuration ||
    !industry ||
    !companyName ||
    !numberOfEmployees ||
    !diamond
  ) {
    return res.status(422).send({ error: "Must provide all project details" });
  }

  try {
    const project = new Project({
      projectName,
      projectDescription,
      projectBudget,
      projectDuration,
      industry,
      companyName,
      numberOfEmployees,
      diamond,
      userId: req.user._id,
    });

    const recommendation = await Recommendation.find({
      "diamond.criteria": criteria,
    }); //Need to render this on front-end somehow!
    const projectsWithSameDiamond = await Project.find({
      "diamond.criteria": criteria,
    }); //Need to render this on front-end somehow!
    
    const projectsWithSameIndustry = await Project.find({ industry }); //Need to render this on front-end somehow!
    
    console.log(res);
    
    

    res.send(
      `Your project:\n\n${project}\n\nSimilar industry: ${projectsWithSameDiamond}\n\nSimilar diamonds: ${projectsWithSameIndustry}\n\nRecommendation: ${recommendation}`
    );
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(422).send({ error: err.message });
  }
});
```

As you can see I am sending many variables in response. I would like to retrieve them in components in a react native project. I can do something like this:

```
const A = () => {
 
              axios.post("/projects", {
                projectName,
                projectDescription,
                projectBudget,
                projectDuration,
                industry,
                companyName,
                numberOfEmployees,
                diamond,
              })
              .then((result) => {
                console.log("I am result!");
                console.log(result.data);
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.response.data);
              });
    

}
```

Now in `result` I am able to retrieve the data but I want to retrieve, store and render the three variables that I put in the response on the front-end? How can I retrieve and store them?

For example like this:

```
const A = () => {
 ...
 return(
 <Text>{recommendation}<Text>
 <Text>{projectWithSimilarDiamond}<Text>
 <Text>{projectWithSimilarIndustry}</Text>
);

}
```

How can I possibly achieve this? I am pretty clueless at the moment.

Comment: What do you mean by "store" the data? Do you want to have the responding data as a state of the React component to render?

Comment: Yes!!! Store so that I can pass it on to different components too. Yes state is the way, but at the moment I was thinking about ```AsyncStorage``` in  react-native.

Answer (score 1):

You should return JSON instead of plain text from the API by using [res.json()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json). This way, you can control how it looks on your application.

```js
res.json({
  project,
  projectsWithSameDiamond,
  projectsWithSameIndustry,
  recommendation,
});
```

For the API calling part, you need to return the Promise object to pass it to the user of the function.

```js
const fetchData = () => {
  return axios
    .post("/projects", {
      projectName,
      projectDescription,
      projectBudget,
      projectDuration,
      industry,
      companyName,
      numberOfEmployees,
      diamond,
    })
    .then((result) => {
      return result.data;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.response.data);
    });
};
```

Then finally React part, you need a convination of [useState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and [useEffect()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for the functional component.

```js
const AComponent = () => {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then((response) => {
      setProjects(response);
    });
  }, []); // you need to define dependency

  if (!projects) {
    // Show loading message untill you get the data
    return <Text>Now loading ...</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Text>{projects.recommendation}</Text>
      <Text>{projects.projectsWithSameDiamond}</Text>
      <Text>{projects.projectsWithSameIndustry}</Text>
    </>
  );
};
```

Regarding `AsyncStorage`, I am not familiar with it. But I believe you can integrate it with `fetchData()` function as something like a cache layer.

```js
const cachedFetchData = async (...args) => {
  const storageKey = "@projects/" + projectName

  // Check if the data is stored on AsyncStorage
  const cached = AsyncStorage.getItem(storageKey)
  if (cached) {
      return JSON.parse(cached)
  }

  // If there is no cache, fetch the data from the APIA
  const data = await fetchData(...args)

  // Then store the data on AsyncStorage
  AsyncStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(data))

  return data
```